# How to calculate the running subtract

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have two table that Table1 contain item and balance, Table 2 contain item and consume, how to calculate the running balance as new column in table 2? (Balance - consume might be negative: shortage)

Table 1

| Item | Balance |
| --- | --- |
| A | 100 |
| B | 200 |
| C | 500 |

Table 2

| Item | consume |
| --- | --- |
| A | 10 |
| A | 20 |
| A | 20 |
| B | 120 |
| B | 100 |
| C | 100 |
| C | 100 |
| C | 200 |

Expected:

| Item | consume | Running Balance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 90 |
| A | 20 | 70 |
| A | 20 | 50 |
| B | 120 | 80 |
| B | 100 | -20 |
| C | 100 | 400 |
| C | 100 | 300 |
| C | 200 | 100 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open your `Table 2`in the **PowerQuery** editor and from the **Add Column** tab select **Index Column**

[image]

2. Create a **measure** with the following expression:

```
running subtract = 
VAR cursor =
    MAX('Table 2'[Index])
VAR runtot = 
    CALCULATE(
        SUM('Table 2'[consume]), 
        'Table 2'[Index] <= cursor
    )
VAR balance =
    LOOKUPVALUE('Table 1'[Balance],'Table 1'[Item], MAX('Table 2'[Item]))
RETURN
    balance - runtot
```

3. Put everything together in a **table** visual

[image]

Comment: It's works!! This is what I want!!! Thank you so much, this struggle me lot of time.

Comment: Can it be done by adding this data to new column in Table 2?